# Is it possible to Convert a Non Gantry template ( Plain HTML Template ) to Gantry Template for joomla?

Tags: templates, joomla

I've recently heard about gantry framework, and it's powerful features.
Is It Possible to convert a Plain HTML template to Gantry powered Joomla Template,
I didn't see any tutorials for that in Gantry's Official site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest downloading and installing the default [Gantry Template](http://www.gantry-framework.org/download).

> This is the default Joomla 2.5 and 3.3 template for Gantry that is
>   intended to be used as a basis for building your own templates

(Get the bundle that includes both Gantry and the template, unless you already has installed Gantry).

Then copy the template from your admin area (**Extensions** > **Template manager**, select **Styles** on the right side, open the Gantry template and click <kbd>Copy</kbd>).

Finally, edit `templates/YOURNEWTEMPLATE/index.php` and add the code from your HTML template. You can add your CSS files to the `<head>` tag in this file, or put it in `templates/YOURNEWTEMPLATE/css/YOURNEWTEMPLATE-custom.css` (replace YOURNEWTEMPLATE with your actual template name). If you use this name, Gantry will detect the file automatically.